# SignalR won't send bytes

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-6.0

I have 2 messages:

```
public interface IClient
{
    public struct ReportPayload
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    Task Report(ReportPayload payload);
    
    public struct SetImagePayload
    {
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    }
    Task SetImage(SetImagePayload payload);
}
```

Then call from server hub (ASP.net blazor app):

```
    hub.Clients.All.Report(new IClient.ReportPayload {Message = "foo"});
    hub.Clients.All.SetImage(new IClient.SetImagePayload
    {
        ImageTitle = "aaaaaaaa",
        Bytes = bytes
    });
```

`Report()` works

`SetImage()` doesn't

`SetImage()` starts to work when I remove byte[] from the message

My client:

```
    Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl($"http:localhost:1234/api")
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
    
    Connection.On<IClient.ReportPayload>(nameof(IClient.Report), payload =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Server has reported: {payload.Message}");
    });

    Connection.On<IClient.SetImagePayload>(nameof(IClient.SetImage), payload =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SetImage got the message: {payload.Bytes.Length}");
    });
```

So my conclusion is SignalR fails to serialize byte arrays

I don't get any errors and thats strange

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out?

Comment: @AndreiIvascu nah I work in gamedev now. Good luck trying to solve your stuff

Comment: You could consider using websocket, at least it works as intended